# No error pop-up(s) on edit button click on review page(s)

Tags: bug, review-queues, error-message

When I am reviewing [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/) on StackOverflow, and I have to many pending edits (or any other errors), the pop-up that *should* tell me that, doesn't show up like it does when click on 'edit' on the original question.

**The pop-up(s) that should be shown, when clicking 'edit' is canceled for the given reason**:
[image: To many pending edits]
[image: Another edit is awaiting approval]

Instead, the only thing that happens, is that a `#` is added to the end of the URL, the click event is canceled and nothing is happening.

To see the actual message, I have to visit the original question, and click on the edit button there to see the error.

There are **no** (error) messages in the JavaScript developer console.

I don't know if this is happening on other review types as well.
I've tested it on:

- Review [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/)
- Review [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/)

I used the `Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98 (Official build) (64-bits)` browser.

---

Are there more people with this issue?

Comment: Can you check with a dev console open what the response is you get from the server?

Comment: @rene I've updated my question. There no messages in the console.

Comment: I was more wondering if the POST on `https://stackoverflow.com/review/task-reviewed/{id}` returned an JSON which did contain the error message...

Comment: I've looked into the Network tab; no POST request is being executed.

Comment: Oh, that is weird indeed. Needs a dev to look into. Thanks for checking.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along :-)

Comment: I've looked for a similar question before posting this. Must have missed that one :/